# autosave options in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to turn OFF autosave in Rails?  I don't want modifications to an association to automatically save to the database UNTIL I call save on the parent object.

```
some_parent.some_children << child #should not save, just adds to the association!

some_parent.save #now parent and children are saved!
```

It this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: The `<<` operator on associations is tricksy. It saves the child if the parent is saved, but doesn't if it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be close enough to provide some help.

```
some_parent.some_children.build({:child_attr1 => 'child_val1'})
some_parent.save # should save the new child as well
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply need to declare the some_children association with autosave: false